# MiniZinc type error for trying to print the result

Tags: output, constraint-programming, type-systems, minizinc

I'm sketching scheduling of bank swizzles in r600g driver *(it's [inefficient ATM](https://github.com/mesa3d/mesa/blob/b7ee56b5991e02bf4bff4ca702182bf37e59aa07/src/gallium/drivers/r600/r600_asm.c#L560-L600), I'm figuring out the constraints)*:

```
enum CHANS = {x,y,z,w};
enum REGS = {R1, R2, R3, R4}; % for starters

% args
enum OPERANDS = {src1, src2, src3, src4};
array[OPERANDS] of REGS: Regs = [R1, R2, R1, R3];
array[OPERANDS] of CHANS: Chans = [x, x, y, x];
array[OPERANDS] of 1..4: Inst = [1,1,2,2];
array[OPERANDS] of 1..3: Port = [1,2,1,2];

% the rest
array[OPERANDS] of var 1..3: PortOut;
constraint sum(i in PortOut where i = 1)(1) <= 3;
constraint sum(i in PortOut where i = 2)(1) <= 3;
constraint sum(i in PortOut where i = 3)(1) <= 3;

output [show(Regs[op]) ++ "." ++ show(Chans[op]) ++ " " | op in OPERANDS where PortOut[op] == 1]
    ++ [show(Regs[op]) ++ "." ++ show(Chans[op]) ++ " " | op in OPERANDS where PortOut[op] == 2]
    ++ [show(Regs[op]) ++ "." ++ show(Chans[op]) ++ " " | op in OPERANDS where PortOut[op] == 3];
solve satisfy;
```

It works with the 3 "output" lines commented out, but otherwise it fails with:

```
λ minizinc test.mzn                                                  
test.mzn:17:
MiniZinc: type error: invalid type in output item, expected `array[int] opt string'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: May be that downvoting smart guy even going to give the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using decision variables in the `output` section you (might) have to use `fix` to use the value of the variable. Here the `PortOut[op]` need to be `fix`'ed:

```
output [show(Regs[op]) ++ "." ++ show(Chans[op]) ++ " " | op in OPERANDS where fix(PortOut[op]) == 1]
++ [show(Regs[op]) ++ "." ++ show(Chans[op]) ++ " " | op in OPERANDS where fix(PortOut[op]) == 2]
++ [show(Regs[op]) ++ "." ++ show(Chans[op]) ++ " " | op in OPERANDS where fix(PortOut[op]) == 3];
```